# Choosing a language on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, languages

Today, I received a notification that said that I have earned a new privilege. It had some of the text in (what I assume to be) Russian. Does it have anything to do with the ongoing war or is there an option to change languages (similar in other social networks)? If so, what other options are there?

[image]

Comment: It is a known race condition issue that is being reviewed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376522/wrong-language-in-recent-achievements